# Alias path precedence rule?

Tags: path-aliases

I just checked that an alias path named, say, `any/path` can point to N different existing paths. Is there any fixed precedence order as per which one will be processed? Or is it a random order?

Comment: Well, right you are, still - and looks like a specific language has precedence over neutral. I just don't know if this is a random behavior or a rule-of-thumb.

Comment: From the user interface it is not possible to have two records for the same path alias, and the same language, but pointing to different internal paths. Calling `path_save()` it is possible. See my answer to understand which alias would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the user interface, it is not possible to set the same alias pointing to different destinations for the same language.
If a module would execute code similar to the following one, it would be possible to have two records for the same alias.

```
$path = array(
  'alias' => 'homepage',
  'source' => 'node/1',
);
path_save($path);

$path = array(
  'alias' => 'homepage',
  'source' => 'node/2',
);
path_save($path);
```

[drupal_lookup_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7) contains the following code to retrieve the internal path associated with a path alias from the database. `$path_language` is the last argument passed to the function; when the function doesn't get that argument, it uses the value of `$GLOBALS['language_url']->language`.

```
    if ($path_language == LANGUAGE_NONE) {
      unset($args[':language']);
      $alias = db_query("SELECT alias FROM {url_alias} WHERE source = :source AND language = :language_none ORDER BY pid DESC", $args)->fetchField();
    }
    elseif ($path_language > LANGUAGE_NONE) {
      $alias = db_query("SELECT alias FROM {url_alias} WHERE source = :source AND language IN (:language, :language_none) ORDER BY language DESC, pid DESC", $args)->fetchField();
    }
    else {
      $alias = db_query("SELECT alias FROM {url_alias} WHERE source = :source AND language IN (:language, :language_none) ORDER BY language ASC, pid DESC", $args)->fetchField();
    }
```

If `$path_language` is equal to `LANGUAGE_NONE` (i.e. you are looking for the internal path associated with the language-independent alias), `drupal_lookup_path('source')` returns the internal path which is saved in the path_alias table with the higher pid (which normally is the latest created row).
If `$path_language` is not equal to `LANGUAGE_NONE`, the database rows are ordered to get the language-specific alias before the language-neutral, and then by pid. Also in this case, the returned internal path would be the last created one.

Suppose url_alias contains the following values.

```
pid   | source    | alias      | language
4     | node/1    | homepage   | und
5     | node/2    | homepage   | und
8     | node/21   | homepage   | it
9     | node/22   | homepage   | it
10    | node/31   | homepage   | xx-lolspeak
11    | node/32   | homepage   | xx-lolspeak
```

What I would get from that table is:

- `drupal_lookup_path('source', 'homepage')`: node/2
  It returns the last created alias that is language-independent.
- `drupal_lookup_path('source', 'homepage', 'es')`: node/2
  There isn't an alias for Spanish, and the function fallback to the language-independent alias. It gets the last created alias.
- `drupal_lookup_path('source', 'homepage', 'xx-lolspeak')`: node/32
  It returns the last created alias for Lol Speak.